# Lottery app , trouble with code

Tags: c++, sorting

I'm in my first year and second term of IT: programmer analyst and I am having some trouble with my code to come up with a lottery app.

All I have to do is output 3 rows of 7 numbers for the lotto max in random between 1-49, and then out put 6 numbers for the "tag", I'm having no trouble with the "tag" part because with tag you don't need to have the numbers in order and you can have 0's and also you can have duplicates of the numbers.

But with the lotto max part with the 3 rows of 7 numbers each, they need to be in assending order from left to right and completely random, also with no 0's.

Here is my code so far, which works but doesnt order the numbers, although I think it is random and without 0's.

code:

```
//Lotto.cpp
#include <iostream> // input out put stream
#include <time.h> //randomizer 
using namespace std; //prevents redundancy

void main() //main returns nothing
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(0)); //random uses time for this function

    while(true) // while its true; repeats upon enter key
    {
        //randomizes any 7 numbers between 1 and 50 and outputs all seven in three separate rows
        cout << "\n               **********Zachattack's Lotto Experience**********" << "\n                                 Good Luck!!!" << endl;
        cout << "\n                             " << (rand() % 49) + 1 << " " << (rand() % 49) + 1 << " " << (rand() % 49) + 1 << " " << (rand() % 49) + 1 << " " << (rand() % 49) + 1 << " " << (rand() % 49) + 1 << " " << (rand() % 49) + 1;
        cout << "\n                             " << (rand() % 49) + 1 << " " << (rand() % 49) + 1 << " " << (rand() % 49) + 1 << " " << (rand() % 49) + 1 << " " << (rand() % 49) + 1 << " " << (rand() % 49) + 1 << " " << (rand() % 49) + 1;
        cout << "\n                             " << (rand() % 49) + 1 << " " << (rand() % 49) + 1 << " " << (rand() % 49) + 1 << " " << (rand() % 49) + 1 << " " << (rand() % 49) + 1 << " " << (rand() % 49) + 1 << " " << (rand() % 49) + 1 << endl;

        //randomizes 6 different numbers between 0 and 9 for the Tag
        cout << "\n                            ***In the Bag Tag!***             \n\n                                    " << rand() % 10 << rand() % 10 << rand() % 10 << rand() % 10 << rand() % 10 << rand() % 10 << endl;

        system("pause>nul");
    }
}
```

Comment: Good Luck, Zachattack!!!

Comment: `prevents redundancy` prevents sane code, you mean

Comment: `main` _must_ return `int`. It may not return `void`, ever. What book are you using? It must be discarded immediately. You should also be using `ctime` not `time.h`, and try a few linebreaks here and there to make your code legible.

Comment: Oh, and comments like `while(true) // while its true` (`it's`*) are completely useless. Avoid them.

Comment: To "answer" your question, so store the numbers in an array or a container, and sort them before output. What specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: What, exactly, is your question?

Comment: Minor point: prefer `for(;;)` to `while(true)` as most compilers will spit out a warning (depending on specified warning level) like "conditional expression is constant" with `while(true)` or `while(1)`.

Comment: @hmjd: I've never seen that, and I keep my warning levels high.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, one I prepared earlier with VS2010 -W4:    `warning C4127: conditional expression is constant`

Comment: Do you need to also prevent duplicates. Otherwise a stange lottery.

Comment: @hmjd: Oh, I stay away from that heap :)

Answer (score 0):

Create 21 random numbers between 1 and 49:

```
int randomNumbers[21];
for(int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
    randomNumbers[i] = rand() % 49 + 1;
```

Then you order the numbers:

```
Quicksort(randomNumbers, 0, 20);
```

And finally you print them the way you want.

You can find the quicksort c++ code at [wikipedia](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort). Here it is, anyway:

```
int colocar(int *v, int b, int t)
{
    int i;
    int pivote, valor_pivote;
    int temp;

    pivote = b;
    valor_pivote = v[pivote];
    for (i=b+1; i<=t; i++){
        if (v[i] < valor_pivote){
                 pivote++;    
                temp=v[i];
                v[i]=v[pivote];
                v[pivote]=temp;

        }
    }
    temp=v[b];
    v[b]=v[pivote];
    v[pivote]=temp;
    return pivote;
} 

void Quicksort(int* v, int b, int t)
{
     int pivote;
     if(b < t){
        pivote=colocar(v, b, t);
        Quicksort(v, b, pivote-1);
        Quicksort(v, pivote+1, t);
     }  
}
```

Comment: Or use `std::sort`... Why would you reinvent sorting?

Answer (score 0):

Do it like the lotto machine does it.  Load all the numers from 1-49 into a list/array. Use rand() to create an index 0-48, get the number from the list at that index and replace it with '0' to flag that it's been drawn. Repeat, (ignoring any '0's that are retrieved), until 21 numbers have been drawn. Sort.

Comment: ..or do it 7 times and recreate the array.  I'm not sure exactly how the lotto works.  I guess the full set of balls are used for each run of 7?

Comment: I don't know where you are from, but that's not how the lottery works around here (or any other place I know): they shuffle the list of numbers and then simple yields the first 'n' elements of the array. Unlike your proposed algorithm, this one is actually guaranteed to terminate, too.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe - OK, I admit that there is a chance of my algorithm not terminating.  Not exactly a big chance, though - about the same as my own chance of winning, (and I don't play :).  At least, my design mirrors the way the machine works - all the 49 balls are shoved in the machine, one is picked at random and not replaced, repeat another 6 times.  To be sure of termination, a list could be used and the element actually removed from it, leaving 1-48 to choose from the second time.  I don't think such an 'optimization' is worth it.

Answer (score 0):

As the other folks beat me to an answer, I will just add that using the already provided algorithms is usually better than implementing from scratch.  Also, you have to store the random numbers somewhere if you are going to sort them.  In this case, I used the already provided vector class.  Also I believe in C++ you should use the header ctime and not time.h even though they are really the same thing I believe.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()  {
   //set up the lottery parameters
   const int GROUPS = 3;
   const int NUMBERS_PER_TICKET = 7;

   //seed the random generator
   srand((unsigned int)time(0));

   //declare the datastructure for holding the numbers
   std::vector<int> numbers[GROUPS];

/* fill our three 7 number groups
   by generating them */
for (int j = 0; j < GROUPS; ++j) {
   for (int i = 0; i < NUMBERS_PER_TICKET; ++i) {
       numbers[j].push_back((rand() % 49) + 1);
   }
}

//now sort them using the built-in sort algorithm
for (int i = 0; i < GROUPS; ++i) {
    std::sort(numbers[i].begin(), numbers[i].end());
}

    //now print in order by line
    for (int j = 0; j < GROUPS; ++j) {
       std::cout<<"Line: " << j + 1 << " :";
       for (int i = 0; i < NUMBERS_PER_TICKET; i++) {
          std::cout<< " " << numbers[j].at(i);
       }
       std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

1. Build an array of 49 numbers
2. Shuffle the array
3. Sort the first 7 numbers, print them
4. Sort the next 7 numbers, print them

Keep repeating step 4. for as many rows you need (at most 7 ;-)). Here's a code sample which implements this strategy. No checking for duplicates needed.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

// This function is courtesy of http://benpfaff.org/writings/clc/shuffle.html
void shuffle(int *array, size_t n)
{
    if (n > 1) {
        size_t i;
        for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            size_t j = i + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (n - i) + 1);
            int t = array[j];
            array[j] = array[i];
            array[i] = t;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    srand( time( NULL ) );

    std::vector<int> numbers( 49 );
    for ( int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i )
        numbers[i] = i + 1;

    shuffle( &numbers[0], numbers.size() );

    std::vector<int>::iterator rowIt = numbers.begin();
    for ( int i = 0; i < 3; ++i ) {
        std::vector<int>::iterator rowEnd = rowIt + 7;
        std::sort( rowIt, rowEnd );

        std::cout << "Row " << i << ":";
        while ( rowIt != rowEnd )
            std::cout << " " << *rowIt++;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok first have a look at loops, mostly the **for** loop. It should be used to generate the random numbers. For example, to fill an array with 6 random numbers between 1 and 49 you can use:

```
int i, numbers[6];
for ( i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
   numbers[ i ] = 1 + rand()%49
}
```

In your question you say that numbers must be completely random, but I feel you imply that numbers must be unique within the array. If this is the case you should check if each number already exists in the array before adding it again. You can do this with a set structure, but for simplicity you can use something like:

```
int i, j, num, duplicates, numbers[6];
for ( i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {   
   do { 
       num = 1 + rand()%49;
       duplicates = 0;
       for ( j = 0; j < i; j++ ) {
           if ( numbers[ j ] == num ) duplicates = 1;
       }
   } while (duplicates);
   numbers[ i ] = num;
}
```

Once you have the numbers in the array, you can sort them. You can use qsort:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/qsort/

This should be enough to get you started.
Good luck :)

Comment: Don't spread links to that site, please. The reference has errors and the tutorials/examples demonstrate poor coding practices.